# Address of an array and address of the address of an array

Tags: c

I have a conflict in this code

```
 `int main(){
int arr[3][4]={1,2,3,4,
           4,3,2,1,
           7,8,9,0};


 printf("%x %x %x \n",arr,arr+1,&arr+1);
 return 0;}`
```

The output appears to me as follows:
9278fc40 9278fc50 9278fc70

what is the difference  between arr+1 , &arr+1 :
I didn't get the relation

Could anyone help please

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is array name a pointer in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641957/is-array-name-a-pointer-in-c)

Comment: there's no "address of address of array" in this question anywhere. It may be helpful for you to know that arrays decay (are implicitly converted) into a pointer to their first element in many cases. Here, passing `arr` to the function will actually pass a pointer to its first element (`&arr[0]`). `arr + 1` is no different: it will result in `&arr[1]`. Now `&arr + 1` is a different beast – as the operand of unary `&`, the array does not decay into a pointer, so what `&arr` means is: a pointer-to-2D-array, or `int (*)[3][4]`. Now I guess you can figure out the rest.

Answer (score 0):

For the two first parameters, you are printing the *memory addresses* of the int values arr[0][0], arr[0][1].  &arr + 1 is different.  The + 1 here iterates the column.  So &arr + 1 actually points to the memory address of the first int of the second column.

Comment: You're incorrect on the second and third analysis, and only partially correct on the first. The first yields the address of `arr[0]`, which *then* converts to a pointer that yields the address of `arr[0][0]`. The second converts to a pointer addressing `arr[1]`, which then converts to a pointer addressing `arr[1][0]`. Finally, `&arr + 1` points to the first `int[3][4]` *after* `arr` (of which there is none).  The last expression yields an address that falls *nowhere* in the defined region of the `arr` array of arrays.

Comment: Dang! You are so right!  What was I thinking.  After your post I went to check &arr + 1 with the debugger just to make sure.  You should write this (I mean your comment) as a correct answer.